# Simplifying logical expressions

Tags: c, logic, conditional-statements

NOTE: This is **NOT** homework.

I want to come up with the right approach to designing the right algorithm to deal with this simple problem.

I have a state (representable with a positive integer) which changes over time. I have another value which is a constant specific state (representable with a particular positive integer) which the first state may become equal to.

It is best illustrated thus:

```
// this is C pseudocode

int things_happen(int *value) {
  ... // value possibly gets changed!
}

const int y = VALUE_Y_CONST; 
int x = y; // to simplify things we assume x starts out equal to y

while (things_happen(&x)) {
  // I am now interested in changes to x with respect to y. 
  if (/* expression of interest */) { 
    x_is_changed(); // I want to know whenever x is no longer y
  }
  if (/* another expression of interest */) {
    x_is_back(); // and I want to know whenever x becomes equal to y again
  }
}
```

How do I go about determining when I should be calling `x_is_changed()` and `x_is_back()`?

I have run into this situation several times by now, when trying to program things. Every time, the solution I come up with looks unreasonably complicated, and often there are bugs.

So far, my solutions require me to create a third variable, which I use to cache the value of x at the bottom of that `while` loop. It allows me to know which value my x has **changed from**. With this knowledge I then use what seems like entirely too many conditional statements:

```
int x_cache = y;
while(things_happen(&x)) {
  if (x_cache != x) {
    if (x == y && x_cache != y)
      x_is_back();
    else if (x != y && x_cache == y)
      x_is_changed();
    x_cache = x;
  }
}
```

That is the most succinct possible way I have done it so far. The code is difficult to follow. What I want to know is, isn't there a better algorithm to solve this problem? What kind of approach should I take? I thought I could draw a truth-table, but I can only do that on truth values. I did it with equalities between the 3 variables and got this table:

```
x_cache == x | x_cache == y | x == y  ||  x_is_changed | x_is_back
                                      || 
    T                T          T     ||       F            F 
    T                T          F     ||       F            F
    T                F          T     ||       F            F
    T                F          F     ||       F            F
    F                T          T     ||       F            F
    F                T          F     ||       T            F
    F                F          T     ||       F            T
    F                F          F     ||       F            F
```

This seems to be the only sort of thing I remember from my logic classes. 
I noticed that rows 2,3, and 5 are impossibilities due to transitivity. So i definitely seem to be limiting myself if I only consider the equality checking between the values.

Should I continue to come up with propositional variables, and look for particular combinations that reduce my total number of operations? There's gotta be an easier way to do it? The general problem of coming up with the most efficient algorithm for arbitrary conditions is obviously NP-complete (on the number of variables).

Staring at that table some further, crossing out rows 2, 3, and 5, I see that the condition `x_cache != x` will eliminate the first 4 rows, which is good, then I am left with 3 possibilities. I can see that `x_cache == y` is equal to `x_is_changed` at this point, and also `x == y` is equal to `x_is_back`.

So that means that I can simplify from above to this:

```
...
  if (x_cache != x) {
    if (x == y)
      x_is_back();
    else if (x_cache == y)
      x_is_changed();
    x_cache = x;
  }
...
```

I still feel like this is non optimal. I don't think there exist other relational operators that could help in this problem. It might actually be optimal, now that I think about it.

I intuited that rows 2, 3, and 5 are impossible. Without that knowledge I couldn't reduce the problem to so few operations. Is there some mathematical/logical concept that allows me to systematically perform this "pruning"?

Comment: If you set x_cache to y initially (instead of -1) doesn't that remove the first if?

Comment: i think so. I had the if there because i didn't want to make assumptions, but I guess I already am making one (x starts equal to y)... I updated the question.

Comment: Is it fair to say that you want to call x_is_changed when x transitions from beeing equal to y to being not equal to y, and you want to call x_is_back when x transitions from being not equal to y to being equal to y?

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes that is exactly what I mean. The reason why I didn't express it using words the way you just did is that it is insanely difficult to understand when presented that way. ---- also i hope the new c tag will get me some more viewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest form is:

```
int x_cache = 1;
while(things_happen(&x)) {
  if (x_cache != (x==y)) {
    if (x == y)
      x_is_back();
    else
      x_is_changed();
    x_cache = (x==y);
  }
}
```

Another alternative is

```
for (;;) {
  while (things_happen(&x) && x==y) { }
  if (x==y) break;
  x_is_changed();
  while (things_happen(&x) && x!=y) { }
  if (x!=y) break;
  x_is_back();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work though. `x = y = 2`. `x` changes from 2 to 0. `x` changes from 0 to 1. I do not want to call `x_is_changed` when changing from 0 to 1 because it was not originally on 2.

Comment: Oh, i like that. I was just starting to think in terms of predicating on (x==y).

Comment: There's no way to avoid caching x's value, is there?

Comment: Well, yes actually.  I've added that method.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `break;`? Hmm. Dude i think you just broke my mind

Comment: Alright I think i understand how your second method works. But if I'm trying to implement it without screwing with the things_happen bit (things_happen is the entire rest of the program). I think waht you have been able to do there is offload the storage of previous state to program execution location, which is incredibly clever, but that solution is not generalizable unfortunately. Either way youve earned this accept.

Comment: I'm thinking that things_happen() returns false when you want it to quit.